# How do I fix linux partitioning for disks without reinstalling system?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, disk, storage

I have a server where I have 2 x 1 TB of disks of storage. It seems that I did not configure them well on the start and now I have installed my applications and afraid that I need to reinstall everything because I messed up. Here's the details:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf767587e

Device         Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1          2048   67110911   67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p2      67110912   69208063    2097152     1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p3      69208064 2000407215 1931199152 920.9G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6ce39c7d

Device         Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1          2048   67110911   67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p2      67110912   69208063    2097152     1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p3      69208064 2000407215 1931199152 920.9G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/md1: 1022 MiB, 1071644672 bytes, 2093056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md0: 31.97 GiB, 34325135360 bytes, 67041280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 920.74 GiB, 988638674944 bytes, 1930934912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```
df -Th
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs  6.3G  2.5M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md2       ext4   906G   96G  764G  12% /
tmpfs          tmpfs   32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/md1       ext3   989M  256M  682M  28% /boot
tmpfs          tmpfs  6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

and the following disks information with lsblk:

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 920.9G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 920.7G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:4    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 920.9G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 920.7G  0 raid1 /
```

I would like to have maximum of storage mounted on the system and the necessary for the system, how can I achieve that without messing up the filesystem I have a Ubuntu 22.04? Thanks

Comment: That doesn't seem too bad? You have a 1GB boot partition, a 32GB swap partition (which may not be needed, depending on the available RAM) and 920GB for the system, data and applications. This is all mirrored across both drives for redundancy.
Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @YtvwlD It's that I do not see the 2 TB on df -h, I only see 1TB, I would like to have more storage on / is this because it's replicated for redundancy and the other 1TB is used for raid? How important raid is for a server used for seedboxing? let me know if this answers your question

Comment: yes, you have all data replicated on both drives (RAID 1). This is good for important data you want to keep. If you can afford to lose the data (because you have copies elsewhere), RAID 0 would give you double the capacity.